# Diffrence of command line typing and Runtime.getRuntime().exec() on Windows

Tags: java, cmd, exec, processbuilder

I want to try to e2fsck on Windows with Cygwin exe and dll files.

Fortunately, it works fine when I try to execute it with Windows command line(such as "e2fsck.exe -f test.img").

However, I failed to execute it with JAVA API, Runtime.getRuntime().exec("e2fsck.exe -f test.img").

Exit value of process is 8, and it means operational error of e2fsck. The exit value seems to be returned when e2fsck can not access target file, or target file is invalid.

I found the below things :

1. It's not caused by diffrence of string handling way of cmd.exe and exec().
   Any other cmds on API call, such as ...exec("echo test! >> test.img"), work fine.
   It means that exec() API put the right file path to e2fsck or any other processes.
2. It's not caused by permission deny. As I mented above, test.img is writable by exec().
3. ProcessBuilder could not solve this problem.

I couldn't find actual reason of my problem.

Did I miss somthing else?

Comment: Try `String[] cmd = {"e2fsck.exe", "-f","test.img"}; Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd);`

Comment: As @Sanjeev pointed out, you need to separate commands as elements in an array and not by whitespace.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately, seperated cmd did not work and returned same exit code(8). IMHO, white space is not actual reason of this issue.